# Point Counts on $G$-torsors over Finite Fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

Let's assume we have a $G$-torsor $X_{1} \to X_{2}$, where $G$ is a finite abelian group, and both $X_{1}$ and $X_{2}$ are defined over $\text{Spec}(\mathbb{Z})$.  Is there an easy way to compute $\#X_{2}(\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}})$ in term of $\#X_{1}(\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}})$?  Any references to maybe help me work something like this out?

I'd like to know the above question in some amount of generality.  But for example, if $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are two "*$k$-isogenous*" abelian varieties over a finite field $k$, then

$$\#A_{1}(K) = \#A_{2}(K)$$

for all finite extensions $K$ over $k$.  To see this result, see Corollary 2.3 here (http://virtualmath1.stanford.edu/~conrad/mordellsem/Notes/L03.pdf).  I'm not sure I fully understand what "$k$-isogenous" means.  If $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ are isogenous over $\mathbb{Q}$, are they isogenous over $\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}$ for all prime powers?

Comment: $\#G \#X_2(\mathbb{F}_q) = \sum \#X_1^{\sigma}(\mathbb{F}_q)$ where the $X_1^{\sigma}$ are the twists of $X_1$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. I wouldn't expect much more than that in general.

Comment: "$k$-isogenous" = there is an isogeny between them defined over $k$.

Comment: @FelipeVoloch Thanks for your comment.  I'm a little out of my comfort zone here, so maybe I can ask if my idea of twists is correct.  A twist $X_{1}^{\sigma}$ should be $X \times \sigma /G$ for a $G$-torsor $\sigma \to \text{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}})$.  Is that product and quotient the usual ones, or is there something subtle here?  Finally, the sum you write is over $\sigma \in H^{1}(\mathbb{F}_{p^{n}}, G)$, correct?

Comment: Your notation in the first question of your comment is a bit ambiguous but I think it's correct. For the second question, yes, the twists are described by the $H^1$.